# Android 4.3 with Genymotion uvesafb: failed to execute /sbin/v86d

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

When I start an AVD with Android 4.3 using Genymotion, the player crash and the Virtual Machine in VirtualBox returns this error:

> uvesafb: failed to execute /sbin/v86d
>
> uvesafb: make sure that the s86d helper is installed and executable

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using Windows OS, Open task manager. 
Close all VirtualBox processes which are:

1. VBoxHeadless.exe
2. VBoxSVC.exe
3. VBoxNetDHCP.exe

(you can also right click on any one of them and hit "end process tree").

Restart Genymotion and try to run the virtual device